# illegalStateException while using java matcher class

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching, web-crawler

I am trying to get a webpage, load it into a string builder, using a BufferedReader and then use a regex to look for and retrieve words or in this case groups of words (department names like computer-science, Electrical-Engineering etc..) that match the regex pattern. I am using the Pattern and Matcher class that java provides but am running into an illegalStateException. I have been staring at this code for quite a while and would like some fresh perspective on what the problem might be. I know it has something to do with the **m.find()** and **m.group()** methods. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I would say from the output I am getting, it recognizes the first words that matches the regex and start throwing illegalStateException after that.

I have also posted my code below:

```
public class Parser{

    static StringBuilder theWebPage;
    ArrayList<String> courseNames;
    //ArrayList<parserObject> courseObjects;

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Parser p = new Parser();

        theWebPage = new StringBuilder();
        try {
                URL theUrl = new URL("http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/");
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(theUrl.openStream()));
                String str = null;

                while((str = reader.readLine())!=null)
                {
                    theWebPage.append(" ").append(str);
                    //System.out.println(theWebPage);
                }
                //System.out.println(theWebPage);
                reader.close();

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                System.out.println("MalformedURLException");

            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("IOException");
            }

        p.matchString();
    }

    public Parser()
    {
        //parserObject courseObject = new parserObject();
        //courseObjects = new ArrayList<parserObject>();
        courseNames = new ArrayList<String>();
        //theWebPage=" ";
    }

    public void matchString() 
    {
        String matchRegex = "#\\w+(-\\w+)+";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(matchRegex);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(theWebPage);
        int i=0;
        int x=0;
        //m.reset();

            while(!(m.matches()))
            {
                System.out.println("inside matches method " + i);
                try{

                        m.find();
                     x = m.end();
                    System.out.println( m.group());
                    PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("/Users/xxxx/Desktop/output.txt"));
                    System.setOut(out);

                    //courseNames.add(i,m.group());

                    i++;
                }catch(IllegalStateException e)
                {
                    System.out.println("IllegalStateException");
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    System.out.println("FileNotFound Exception");
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Better to parse web content with http://jsoup.org/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you call:

```
x = m.end();
```

even though you may not have a match. Why not incorporate your call to find() into your while statement, thereby making it a guard statement also:

```
while (m.find()) {
```

Comment: ya that eliminated the exception when I used the While(m.find()) solution that you provided but now it is only recognizing the first pattern and the program terminates without error but the output is incomplete in that there are patterns further down in the file that it is not recognizing. I apologize for being so vague about the error but I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution overcomplicates things a bit. How about this?

```
package MitOpenCourseWareCrawler;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Parser {
    private List<String> courseNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    private URL url;

    public Parser(String url) throws MalformedURLException {
        this.url = new URL(url);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Parser parser = new Parser("http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/");
        parser.parse();
        for (String courseName : parser.courseNames)
            System.out.println(courseName);
    }

    public void parse() throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*<u>(.+)</u>.*");
        Matcher matcher;
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
            if (matcher.matches())
                courseNames.add(matcher.group(1));
        }
        reader.close();
    }
}
```

Besides, I agree with Reimeus that it would probably be a better strategy to use a parsing tool or library than to try and to HTML parsing using regex patterns. But I guess as long as you know the structure of the page and know exactly what you want, a quick'n'dirty solution like yours or mine is okay.